# Impossible to have proper fixed nav in IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have a nav that is fixed to the top of the page. Then I have content below. IE is garbage and the z-index isn't followed. This is for the current version IE.

```
<body>
    <nav>
        <div id="logo"></div>
        <div id='menu'>
            <p data-menuanchor='Home'><a href="http://satprepget800.com/#Home">Home</a></p>

            <p data-menuanchor='Resources'><a href="http://satprepget800.com/#Resources">Resources</a></p

            <p data-menuanchor='About'><a href="http://satprepget800.com/#About">About</a></p>

            <p data-menuanchor='Contact'><a href="http://satprepget800.com/#Contact">Contact</a></p>

            <p><a href="books/">Books</a></p>

            <p><a href="blog/">Blog</a></p>
        </div>
        <div id='social'>
            <a class="desktop" href="https://www.facebook.com/SATPrepGet800" target="_blank"><img class="desktop" src="../wp-content/themes/Get 800/img/facebookIcon.png"></a>

            <a class="desktop" href="https://twitter.com/satprepget800" target="_blank"><img class="desktop" src="../wp-content/themes/Get 800/img/twitterIcon.png"></a>

            <img id='share' src="../wp-content/themes/Get 800/img/shareIcon.png">

        </div>
    </nav>

    <div id='postContainer'>    

            <div class="row "><div class="six columns "><p></p>
            <h3 style="text-align: center;"><b>SAT Math Overview</b></h3>
            <div class="video-container" style="text-align: center;"><iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/5ZdRJz0WSHM?rel=0" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></div>
```

The post container contains iframe videos..

```
nav {
 background-color: #01235f;
 width: 100%;
 height: 10%;
 top: 0;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 9; }

#postContainer {
 width:70%; 
 margin: auto; 
 margin-top: 10%; 
 font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
 font-size: 22px;
 z-index: -1;
 position: relative;
}
```

Why does this not work. Every other browser this works.

Comment: Please show the related CSS

Comment: Okay Done.,.,.,.,.,.,

Comment: Ah, IE doesn't recognise nav as a proper tag. There will be answers for this. I'll find one

Comment: Ah thanks, the styles are being applied though. This is IE11

Answer (score 0):

IE *does* support these features.

If you're not seeing it working, my guess is that the page is being rendered in Quirks mode. This mode puts IE into IE5-compatible mode, which kills loads of browser features.

You can check the browser mode by opening Dev Tools (press F12), and go to the "Emulation tab". If browser mode says "5", then it's quirks mode. Fixing this will solve your problem.

If this is the issue, you can fix it by making sure your HTML code is valid. The most common cause is that you haven't specified a DOCTYPE, but your code in the question is also missing the `<html>` tags and the whole `<head>` section as well as the DOCTYPE. You'll need to add all of these to make it value HTML and get it to render properly.

Comment: It is using Edge as the compatibility mode. I also tried 10 and the same result.

The videos still scroll on top of the nav :/